# Smooth sliding animation and transition in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to animate or ease the incremental scroll left triggered as shown in the below fiddle, but struggling to find the issue with the smooth transition. 
Any help would be really appreciated, thank you

```
function scrollRight() {
i = (i + 1) % elements.length;

jQuery(slider).parent().animate({
  scrollLeft: (width) + 'px'
}, options.hasOwnProperty('speed') ? options.speed : 1000, function() {
  obj.find('li:first-child').appendTo(jQuery(slider).parent().scrollLeft(0).find(slider));

  if (!pause)
    timeout = setTimeout(scrollRight, options.hasOwnProperty('interval') ? options.interval : 2000);
});
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/rshr0Lv5/

Answer (score 1):

remove `max-width: 340px;` in css

Comment: thanks for replying, but I need to somehow keep the main middle part smaller than the overall width of the screen, in order to have this effect of left/right transparent images. Is there any other way to do this apart from max-width maybe?